# Why does "numpy.mean" return 'inf'?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to calculate the mean in columns of an array with more than 1000 rows.

`np.mean(some_array)` gives me 
`inf` as output

but i am pretty sure the values are ok. I am loading a csv from [here](http://www.bliasoft.com/Documents/DataConcrete.txt) into my `Data` variable and column 'cement' is "healthy" from my point of view.

```
In[254]:np.mean(Data[:230]['Cement'])
Out[254]:275.75
```

but if I increase the number of rows
the problem starts:

```
In [259]:np.mean(Data[:237]['Cement'])
Out[259]:inf
```

but when i look at the Data

```
In [261]:Data[230:237]['Cement']
Out[261]:
 array([[ 425. ],
        [ 333.  ],
        [ 250.25],
        [ 491.  ],
        [ 160.  ],
        [ 229.75],
        [ 338.  ]], dtype=float16)
```

i do not find a reason for this behaviour
P.S This happens in Python 3.x using wakari (cloud based Ipython)

Numpy Version '1.8.1'

I am loading the Data with:

```
No_Col=9
conv = lambda valstr: float(valstr.replace(',','.'))

c={}
for i in range(0,No_Col,1):
    c[i] = conv

Data=np.genfromtxt(get_data,dtype=float16 , delimiter='\t', skip_header=0, names=True,   converters=c)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with that data.  Also, the data I see in those row numbers in the CSV is not the same as what you show.  How are you loadng it in?

Comment: Guess: is it overflowing the float? I see you're using a 16-bit float which has a max value of `65504`.

Comment: i edited the question to be more precise.

Comment: I don't get those numbers either, but @Jsor is almost certainly right that it's an overflow.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like the reason.  @Hiatus, why are you using float16?

Comment: i changed it to float32, and it returns a value, but i do not understand why this causes an overflow...

Comment: Aside: standard recommendation -- if you're working with data where you want to name the columns, you're probably better off with [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) than bare numpy.

Comment: Hmm... I am working with `dtype=np.float64`. I used both `np.mean` and `np.nanmean`. I have 7864 nonnull values and I still get `inf`. Excel gives me: 0.332747161. Don't get it.

Comment: Hmmm. Edited: Found some zeros in the base...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I will guess that the problem is precision (as others have also commented).  Quoting directly from the documentation for `mean()` we see

> Notes
>
> The arithmetic mean is the sum of the elements along the axis divided
>     by the number of elements.
>
> Note that for floating-point input, the mean is computed using the
>   same precision the input has.  Depending on the input data, this can
>   cause the results to be inaccurate, especially for `float32` (see
>   example below).  Specifying a higher-precision accumulator using the
>   `dtype` keyword can alleviate this issue.

Since your array is of type float16 you have very limited precision.  Using `dtype=np.float64` will probably alleviate the overflow.  Also see the examples in the `mean()` documentation.