# Why is numpy.mean infinite while values are finite?

Tags: python, numpy

I was playing around with Hypothesis when I came across the following

```
>>> x = np.array([8.988465674311579e+307, 8.98846567431158e+307])
>>> x
array([  8.98846567e+307,   8.98846567e+307])
>>> x.mean()
inf
```

Does this happen because the sum of the elements is `inf`?

```
>>> x.sum()
inf
```

If so, why does numpy not divide first, sum after?

```
>>> (x/len(x)).sum()
8.9884656743115795e+307
```

Comment: If you divide first and sum later I believe the complexity would increase by a factor of array size.

Comment: I suppose the problem is that division is expensive. Perhaps it would it be possible to detect this situation and choose the appropriate method?

Comment: This might do better as an issue filed against numpy, since you've basically diagnosed the problem and a potential solution

Comment: It's not so much that division is expensive, as it is that doing an operation N times is much worse than doing it 1 time. A middle ground would be to sum then divide the small values, but divide then sum the large values

Comment: FWIW, the builtin `statistics.mean([8.988465674311579e+307, 8.98846567431158e+307])` throws an `OverflowError` here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does “numpy.mean” return 'inf'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313649/why-does-numpy-mean-return-inf)

Comment: I'm giving this issue a shot [at the numpy repo](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8313).

Comment: Wouldn't be simpler to let smart users apply the work around in real-world cases where this could be a problem?

Comment: Maybe, but why is that an argument in this case more than with any functionality?

Comment: I stumbled across [an article on the Hypothesis website](http://hypothesis.works/articles/calculating-the-mean/) that talks about this. Unfortunately they don't offer a solution.

Answer (score 2):

`x.mean` is a builtin, so I'd have to look at the github to see exactly how it's coded.  But the straight forward sum followed by divide is most likely.  But it does handle variations like axis and dtype.

My guess is that your case does not come up often enough to merit special treatment.  Routinely dividing by size is not a good idea, since that can lead to a loss of precision.  And it involves an extra iteration through the array.  The alternative is to do the sum(s), and then check if any are `inf` or `overflow` values, and repeat the task with the scaled values.  That too incurs an extra iteration.

But you as the user always have the option of scaling your values appropriately.  Coding your own `mean` with the scaling followed by sum is easy.  If you hit this `inf` problem with `mean` you probably will hit with other calculations with those numbers - anything that involves summing  - weighted average, dot, std, etc.  So you might as well scale the values once, rather than expect each calculation to do it for you.

[Why does "numpy.mean" return 'inf'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313649/why-does-numpy-mean-return-inf)
suggests that this is more likely a problem when you are deliberately limiting the dtype (e.g. with `dtype=np.float16`).

```
In [361]: x=np.array([6550]*1000,dtype=np.float16)
In [362]: x.mean()
Out[362]: inf
In [363]: x.mean(dtype=float)
Out[363]: 6552.0
```

`np.mean` docs talk about the choice of `dtype` and potential loss of precision.  They could have just as well mentioned the overflow issue.

Comment: Several users have mentioned the extra iteration/complexity that my solution would incur, but I'm not sure this is true. Take this implementation: `mean = 0; for i in x: mean += i/len(x)`. Still `O(len(x))`.

Answer (score 0):

Just commented on the issue page on numpy, but I figured I'd post here as well.

The following should work in general, without loss of generality, and as fast as if numpy.mean was calculated in a big-friendly way:

```
def my_mean(x):
    return np.average(x, weights=np.ones_like(x) / x.size)
```

The way you'd fix np.mean would be to multiply by 1/n beforehand--using weights with np.average can do that without loss of generality.

You could also do `(x/len(x)).sum()`, but I think the above would handle rounding of weights better.